# SQL Self-Join Discover Hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, join, grouping, hierarchy

Consider a SQL Server 2017 table (let's call it Products) that has an implied hierarchy based on ordering of primary key (id) with the following logical structure:

```
Product (root)
 - SKU  (optional children)
 - Rule (optional children)
```

An example table might look like this:

```
    ID  Item_Type
    1   Product
    2     SKU
    3     SKU
    4     SKU
    5     Rule
    6     Rule
    7   Product
    8     Rule
    9     Rule
    10  Product
    11    SKU
```

Given I want to find the parent product of each SKU and rule, what would be the appropriate query?  The results should be this:

```
ID  Item_Type ProductId
2     SKU     1
3     SKU     1
4     SKU     1
5     Rule    1
6     Rule    1
8     Rule    7
9     Rule    7
11    SKU     10
```

Comment: What you mean mean by "physical ordering"? Also there's no way to get rows in any order other than the (partial) ordering of an ORDER BY. So it's not clear what you're asking. Plus this shows no research. And when clear this will probably be a faq. Also a code question requires a [mre]. Putting words in scare quotes does not make clear the idiosyncratic specific meaning that you didn't write out. See [ask], [help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Updated physical ordering to mean primary key order.  I would post some research samples here, but it's all rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution.  Likely not the best approach , but it seems to perform sufficiently:

```
select childid, item_type, max(parentId) as productid from (
    select children.*, parents.id as parentId from (
        select id as childId, Item_Type from products where Item_Type in ('SKU', 'RULE')
    ) children
    inner join (
        select id from products 
        where Item_Type in ('Product')
    ) parents
    on parents.id < children.childId
) hierearchy
group by childid, item_type
order by childid
```

Answer (score 0):

A scalar function could be handy too

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindParentKey
(
    @CurrentItemKey int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    return (
        SELECT MAX(ID)
        FROM Product
        WHERE ID < @CurrentItemKey and Item_Type = 'Product'
    )
END
GO

SELECT ID, Item_Type, dbo.FindParentKey(ID)
FROM Product
WHERE Item_Type <> 'Product'
```